# $httpBackend.flush() activates routing

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, karma-runner, karma-mocha, angular-mock

I want to test the following service:

```
"use strict";

const BASE_API = APP_CONF.baseApi;

export default function() {
  "ngInject";

class API {

constructor() {
  this.loading = false;
}

logout() {
  this.loading = true;

  return $http.post(`${BASE_API}/logout`)
    .then(res => {
      this.loading = false;

      return res.data;
    }, err => {
      this.loading = false;

      throw err;
    });
}
}

return new API();

};
```

My test:

```
"use strict";

let baseApi = APP_CONF.baseApi;

describe("Auth service", function() {
 let Auth;

 beforeEach(angular.mock.module("app"));

 beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function(_Auth_) {
   Auth = _Auth_;
 }));

 context("method LOGOUT", function() {
   let $httpBackend;

 beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function(_$httpBackend_) {
   $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
   $httpBackend.whenPOST(`${baseApi}/logout`).respond(200, { data: "ok"});
 }));

 it("should change 'loading' flag", function() {
  Auth.logout();
  assert.isTrue(Auth.loading);
  $httpBackend.flush();
  assert.isFalse(Auth.loading);
 });

 });
});
```

But my test fails with following error:

```
Chrome 51.0.2704 (Linux 0.0.0) Auth service method LOGOUT should change 'loading' flag FAILED
    Error: Unexpected request: GET http://localhost:3000/api/mailboxes
    No more request expected
```

This request is called after route gets resolved:

```
"use strict";

export function config($locationProvider, $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  "ngInject";

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("404");
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

  $stateProvider
   .state("404", {
     url: "/404",
     template: `<view-404 class="v-404" />`
    })
    .state("home", {
      url: "/",
      template: `<view-home class="v-home" />`,
      resolve: {
      mailboxes: function(MailboxesApi, MailboxesStore, $state) {
        "ngInject";

      return MailboxesApi.getAll() // THIS LINE ACTIVATES UNEXPECTED REQUEST
        .then(mailboxes => {
          MailboxesStore.set(mailboxes);

          let inbox = MailboxesStore.getByName("inbox");

          if (inbox) {
            $state.go("cabinet.mailbox", { mailboxid: inbox._id });
          } else {
            $state.go("cabinet.mailbox", { mailboxid: MailboxesStore.getByIndex(0)._id });
          }
        });
      }
     }
    });

  };

  export function run($transitions) {
    "ngInject";

    $transitions.onError({ to: "*" }, (ErrorHandler, $error$) => {
     "ngInject";

     ErrorHandler.handle($error$);
    });

   };
```

I noticed that state 'home' is activated after the $httpBackend.flush() was called in my test. Why does it happen?

My dependencies:

- angular-mocks 1.5.7
- angular 1.5.6
- angular-ui-router 1.0.0-alpha.5
- karma 0.13.22
- mocha 2.5.3
- chai 3.5.0

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be normal flow of execution after looking into the error details.After flush ( /logout/) its redirecting to home view that is as per your project routing logic. However, when it reached to the home it has something to do with the mailbox API and its expecting one more httpbackend ( GET ) simulation.

I believe you should add one more line in your test case something similar like below

```
$httpBackend.whenGET('url').respond(200, { data: "ok"});
```